# How to restrict characters entered into a textbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML text box which I'm using for a phone number. I want to restrict users from entering characters into that text box using jQuery.

i tried using something like this

```
<input type="text"  onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z]/, '')" />
```

but its allowing characters and restricting numbers

Any ideas highly appreciated.

Comment: No need of jquery for that.html is enought.try how.

Comment: i just tried this one but it is allowing characters and restricting numbers onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z]/, '')" />

Comment: You should check the inputs in your PHP code (or whatever language you are using on the server), because JavaScript can be deactivated on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to validate the number to phone number:

```
 function checkNumber(that){
 if(isNaN(that.value)) 
   { 
     alert("Invalid data format.\n\nOnly numbers are allowed."); 
     that.focus(); 
     return (false); 
   }
  }
```

**EDITED:**

```
<input type="text"  onkeyup="checkNumber(this);" />
```

And you can see the [other codes here](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/phone-no-validation.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type=text]').on('keyup', function(e){
        if (/[^0-9 ]/.test(this.value)) {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9 ]/g, '');
        }
    });
});
```